# Split up interval into year slices

Tags: postgresql, datetime, set-returning-functions

Being a novice Postgres user, I have a table `ad` in my PostgreSQL 9.5 (x64) database with 87 rows. In addition to other columns, it has two columns 'start' and 'end' having date-time duration range like this:

```
ID      Start                   End
1       2003-06-07 00:00:00     2004-09-30 23:59:59
```

I need to split the range into one year windows in separate rows (from start year to the last year of interval) stored in database like this:

```
ID       Start
1_2003   2003-06-07 00:00:00     2003-12-31 23:59:59
1_2004   2004-01-01 00:00:00     2004-09-30 23:59:59
```

Using the operator `||'_'||` and `Extract()` function, I am able to concatenate ID with year. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378026/splitting-up-an-interval-in-weeks-in-postgres) addresses how to split up in interval in weeks and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454943/postgresql-splitting-time-range-into-days) shows how to do the same for days but none of them addresses how to split up an interval in years specifically.

I avoided [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454943/postgresql-splitting-time-range-into-days) because I don't want to go for a stored procedure based approach. I am aware that `generate_series()` returns a series from start and stop parameters but actually I am struggling to break the interval at last day of the year and then re-starting from first day of the year in next row. I would highly appreciate if someone could guide me to this?

Comment: Look at the [example](http://pastebin.com/HtPQweQc). Read about CTE [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), about `generate_series` function [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) and about range types [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html). Good luck.

Comment: It looks like `start` and `end` do not need a time component, since you always work with whole days? Correct? And please *always* provide your version of Postgres and the table definition showing data types and constraints.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: That's true. I need a timestamp (date-time with year) and not specifically a time component only. I am using PostgresSQL version 9.5. Table "ad" contains 87 rows. Start and End columns are in data type 'timestamp without time zone' and ID column is of type 'text'.

Comment: BTW, you link to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454943/postgresql-splitting-time-range-into-days) twice, but I suspect the second time is by mistake since you mention "stored procedures" which are not involved.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: You are so right. Mentioning your answer twice was unintentional because I saw stored procedure based approach as well and I did not want to use that specifically.

Comment: ||'_'|| kicked in my pareidolia.  That's adorable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- Use [legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860) to save yourself a lot of confusion. `end` (and, to a lesser degree `start`) are [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).
- Your `id` column seems to be [numeric type like `integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html), not `text`.
- Since you don't need a time component in `start_day` and `end_day`, the appropriate data type is [`date`, not `timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).
- Why concatenate `id` and the year for a new "ID"? Add a second column `year` if you need it for a PK. Or don't add an additional column at all. It can cheaply be extracted from the new `start_day` on the fly. Generally, don't store data redundantly if you can avoid it.
- Typically, `timestamp` ranges use an inclusive lower bound and an **exclusive upper bound**. Since timestamps can have fractional digits (up to 6 in Postgres) that is much cleaner. Your input `2003-12-31 23:59:59` would fail for `2003-12-31 23:59:59.123`.

So, your table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ad (
  id        int PRIMARY KEY
, start_day date NOT NULL    -- *inclusive* lower bound
, end_day   date NOT NULL    -- *exclusive* upper bound
CHECK (end_day > start_day)  -- enforce legal input
);
```

Proper test values:

```
INSERT INTO ad(id, start_day, end_day)
VALUES
  (1, '2003-06-07', '2004-10-01')   -- span 2 years (your example)
, (2, '2003-06-07', '2003-06-08')   -- 1 day in same year
, (3, '2003-06-07', '2003-10-01')   -- span 1 year
, (4, '2003-06-07', '2006-10-01');  -- span many years
```

#### Solution

Use `generate_series()` in a [`LATERAL` join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860), based on start and end day, truncated to the year with `date_trunc()`. This produces one row per year with the *new start date*. Add a year and you have the *new end date*. Except for first and last row per `id`, where you substitute the proper start / end with [`GREATEST` and `LEAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) respectively. Voilá.

```
-- CREATE TABLE ad_year AS
SELECT ad.id
     , extract('year' FROM y)::int AS year
     , GREATEST(y                    , ad.start_day) AS start_day
     , LEAST   (y + interval '1 year', ad.end_day)   AS end_day
FROM   ad
     , generate_series(date_trunc('year', start_day::timestamp)  -- cast to ts here!
                     , date_trunc('year', end_day::timestamp)
                     , interval '1 year') y;
```

Note that [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) returns `timestamptz` for `timestamptz` input and `timestamp` for `timestamp` input. For `date` input it defaults to `timestamptz`. Since you seem to be ignoring time zones, cast the `date` to `timestamp` explicitly (`start_day::timestamp`).

Result:

```
 id | year |      start_day      |       end_day
----+------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | 2003 | 2003-06-07 00:00:00 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00
  1 | 2004 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 2004-10-01 00:00:00
  2 | 2003 | 2003-06-07 00:00:00 | 2003-06-08 00:00:00
  3 | 2003 | 2003-06-07 00:00:00 | 2003-10-01 00:00:00
  4 | 2003 | 2003-06-07 00:00:00 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00
  4 | 2004 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 2005-01-01 00:00:00
  4 | 2005 | 2005-01-01 00:00:00 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00
  4 | 2006 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 2006-10-01 00:00:00
```

If you create a new table from the result, I suggest `(id, year)` as primary key.

Aside: This is not an operator: `||'_'||` (nor a cute little face). It's  2 [concatenation operators `||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) and a string literal `'_'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and useful suggestions. Much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. It's a bit messy but you can probably figure out how to take it from here.

```
select 
    x.id||'_'||extract('year' from x.series) as id,
    case 
            when extract('year' from x.start) = extract('year' from x.series) then x.series 
            else date_trunc('year', x.series) 
    end as start,
    case 
            when extract('year' from x.end::timestamp) = extract('year' from x.series) then x.end
            else date_trunc('year', x.series) + interval '1 year' - interval '1 second' 
    end as finish 
from
    (select 
            'id' as id, 
            '2003-06-07 00:00:00'::timestamp as start,
            '2006-09-30 23:59:59'::timestamp as end,
            '2003-06-07 00:00:00'::timestamp 
                    + generate_series(0,
                            datediff('year', 
                                    date_trunc('year','2003-06-07 00:00:00'::timestamp), 
                                    date_trunc('year', '2006-09-30 23:59:59'::timestamp)
                                    )
                            )                                                
                    *interval '1 year' as series
    ) x;
```

Comment: Just one note: day have no the inclusive upper bound for the `timestamp(tz)` type, mention the value like `2006-09-30 23:59:59.123456789` for example.

Comment: @peach: Thanks for your feedback. It was indeed helpful.